# How to change the background of the game when touching edge

Tags: python, pgzero

I'm making a rpg game in pygame and I don't know how to make the background change when touching edge  and when I try, it won't work and it says a syntax error at line 31

```
import pygame
WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 365
player = Actor("character.png")
player.pos = WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2
player.posx = WIDTH/2
player.posy = HEIGHT/2
tent = Actor("tent2.png")
tent.pos = WIDTH/3, HEIGHT/1.3
campfire = Actor("campfire.png")
campfire.pos = WIDTH/5, HEIGHT/1.3

def update():
    if keyboard.a and player.left > 0:
        player.left -= 3
    if keyboard.d and player.right < WIDTH:
        player.right += 3
    if keyboard.w and player.top > 0:
        player.top -= 3
    if keyboard.s and player.bottom < HEIGHT:
        player.bottom += 3

if player.pos = WIDTH/1, HEIGHT/1:
        screen.blit("bg3.png",(0,0))
```

Comment: This is not [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news), it is [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). You have to use the [tag:pgzero] tag instead of the [tag:pygame] tag.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st argument of [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) must be a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) object. Use [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) to load new image from a file and to create a *Surface*.

Load the file once:

```py
bg3_surf = pygame.image.load("bg3.png")
```

And use it later in your code:

<s>`screen.blit("bg3.png",(0,0))`</s>

```py
screen.blit(bg3_surf, (0, 0))
```